# Routing in angular too quick for my observables

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Whenever someone edits or adds a project in my application, I route them back to the project overview. However, when they arrive at the overview page, the new projects isn't visible yet and the edits are not visible for the edited projects. When they then navigate to another page and back to the project overview, everything is fine. How do I make it such that the overview page waits for the updates before showing the projects?

Here is some of my code:

Project-overview HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Projects</h3>
        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" sortable="description" (sort)="onSort($event)">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col" sortable="entity" (sort)="onSort($event)">Entity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let project of projects" [routerLink]="['/projects/edit/', project.projectId]" >
                    <td>{{project.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{project.entity}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <div class="text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/projects/add/">Add new project</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Add-projects component:

```
submitProject() {
    this.projectService.addProject(this.project).subscribe(
      () => {},
      (err) => console.log(err),
      () => this.router.navigate(['/projects'])
    );
  }
```

Projects-component:

```
getProjects() {
    this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(projects => this.projects = projects)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProjects();
  }
```

Project-service:

```
addProject(project: Project): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Project>(this.url, project, this.httpOptions)
  }

  getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Project[]>(this.url)
  }
```

If any additional code is required, please tell me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "too quick"? Are you getting an error? This isn't linked to the speed of routing - `getProjects` will only start executing when the projects component is loaded. Could you show how the `projects` property is used - either in HTML or the component, or both.

Comment: no I don't get an error, but the project I just added doesn't show in the overview until I go to a different page and then back, so it's like the overview loading is quicker than the project adding

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Every `http request` in Angular, work `asynchronously` and javascript is a language with single thread. So if you call `http.get` or any other method, the callback which you pass as argument, will be executed after data arrives and when thread is free (it is http callback time to be executed). You can use `Resolvers` to fetch data before component render, or you can wrap your Html code in f.e `ng-container` with `ngIf` and render the part of code if required property is not null/undefined. Here is documentation link: 
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Answer (score 0):

The routing is not 'too quick', but you are requesting data way ahead of the processing your API is going to do on POST of a new project, hence if you immediatly try to get a updated list your API will just not response with the newest project within the response. You can tackle this issue in different ways and there isn't one right way to do it.

Some solutions would be

1. Poll your projects in an interval
2. Introduce Server-sent events to keep the list in sync
3. Delay the request of the list (bad practice)
4. Rework your POST endpoint so it only response after successfully creating the new project